# Hostapd in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless-access-point

When using Hostapd in Ubuntu why can my wireless card change to the nl80211 driver that hostapd supports ?

My wireles driver is Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1509
    Kernel driver in use: brcm80211
    Kernel modules: brcm80211

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking why your wireless driver isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your wireless card change to the nl80211 driver that hostapd supports you need to use a different driver for your wifi-card. As you mentioned driver in use is brcm80211, it does not support nl80211. You need to use brcmsmac driver for your card which comes installed with ubuntu 11.04,11.10.